# Fxcop check while SVN Commit

Tags: tortoisesvn, fxcop

Can I check for any Fxcop errors and block the SVN commit of file(s)? Can this be done in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This certainly seems like it would be possible with a Subversion [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks).  However if you are checking in source, the hook would require building your project followed by a run of FxCop on the output binary.  This would make the post-commit hook very slow and your commits would appear to hang while everything was going on.

My opinion is that this sort of thing should be done with a continuous integration environment rather than as a commit hook.

Comment: I have this already done in my CIE. Coming to the "Post-Commit" part - Can I implement a post-commit-hook in the repository, by which all the users will be affected by the hook? NB: I'm not the admin of the repo.

Comment: You certainly could, but you would likely need elevated privileges to modify the repository's post-commit hook.  The hook will need to invoke your build process with all of the issues there (what server the build runs on, installation of build tools, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TortoiseSVN, you can configure a client-side pre-commit hook script as described in the [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).

Comment: So that means, I would have to create the same hook in all my developer machines individually for everyone to be in sync -- right?